# How to set a check box in every row with one button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have attempted to create event attached to a button to go through each row of the grid view to change the checked value to equal true. How make it so once I click this button it mark every thing to true?

This is the code I have started with:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{ 
    //I get stuck at this part
    row.Cells[9].FindControl("Overwrite")
}
```

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, you should be able to avoid a postback by making a javascript function to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `GridView` markup, if you use a `TemplateField` to hold the `CheckBox` control, then you can write easier `FindControl` code to actually locate the `TextBox` control, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Visible="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action Item">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Overwrite" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now in your code-behind, you can do this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    // Only check data rows, ignoring header or footer rows
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    { 
        CheckBox b = row.FindControl("Overwrite") as CheckBox; 

        if(b != null)
        {
            b.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You do not need the `Cells` index anymore, because `FindControl` can search the entire row looking for a control named `Overwrite`.

Comment: You don't need those brackets around `b.Checked = true;`.

Comment: @JoeTyman - yes, technically you are right, but if there is more than one line in the `if` block, then you do need them and I almost always have more than one statement in my `if` block, so it is a habit. :-)

Comment: I know, I personally like to fit as much as I can on one line, assuming it is under 80 columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{ 
    CheckBox b = row.Cells[9].FindControl("Overwrite") as CheckBox; 
    b.Checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <div class="form-group" style="display:flex; justify-content:center">
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mb-3" type="submit">Sign in</button>
     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
       <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" checked="">
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Remember me</label>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

This is a Sample HTML consisting of Styles. You can use it like this/ this is not the ans for this question